Casimir functions and Liouville integrability
On the one hand, on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, one has the notion of Liouville (or complete) integrability, where one has a complete set of Poisson-commuting functions $\{h_i\}_{i\leq n}$: $$\{h_i,h_j\}=0$$
for all $i,j\leq n$, satisfying some additional independence conditions.
On the other hand, on a Poisson manifold $(Q,\{\cdot,\cdot\})$, one also has the notion of Casimir functions, i.e. functions in the center (with respect to the Poisson bracket) of $C^\infty(Q)$. A complete set of such functions determine the leaves of the symplectic foliation of $Q$ [1].
Is the main conceptual difference between these two that the latter only determine the leaves,  while the former (restricting to a single symplectic leaf) determine individual points?
References:
[1] Weinstein, A. (1983). The local structure of Poisson manifolds. Journal of differential geometry, 18(3), 523-557

Liouville integrability is, geometrically speaking, a way to 'foliate' the symplectic manifold into Lagrangian leaves. This does not suffice to locate points. For instance, for $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the standard area form, a complete set of Poisson-commuting functions necessarily consists in a single function; the Lagrangian leaves are the level-sets of this single function.
A Poisson algebra is in particular a Lie algebra. As you said, the Casimir elements are those elements that are more generally called 'central', i.e. those that commute with all of the other elements. A 'Liouville complet set' is rather a basis for an abelian subalgebra.
Hence the main conceptual difference between the two is essentially the same as that between the center of a group and an abelian subgroup of the group.

You are indeed entirely right about the functions not spanning a coordinate system as the dimensions do not allign.

And your final remark about the similarity with central and abelian subgroups does make me wonder what other similarities there are.
